# VueRouter - how to reset certain state on every route change

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following `Base.vue` (stripped down, for simplicity):

```vue
<template lang="html">
  <!-- Start Template Root Div -->
  <div class="">
    <router-view
      v-on:modalToggled="scrollYDisabled = !scrollYDisabled"
    />
  </div>
  <!-- End Template Root Div -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Base",
  components: {
    // Initialise components here:
  },
  // All props arguments to contain default factory functions, and required bool.
  props: {
    someBoolean: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => false,
      required: false
    }
  },
  // Data is an arrow function returning an object:
  data: () => ({
    someVaribale: false
  }),
  // Computed Properties:
  computed: {},
  // Component Watchers
  watch: {},
  // Component Methods:
  methods: {},
  // Lifecycle Hooks:
  beforeCreate: () => {},
  created: () => {},
  beforeMount: () => {},
  mounted: () => {},
  beforeUpdate: () => {},
  updated: () => {},
  beforeDestroy: () => {},
  destroyed: () => {}
};
</script>
```

As you can see, inside my `data()` setup is a boolean `someVaribale` which I would like to be set to `false` on a route change...

What would be the best practise way to achieve this, preferably without making the URL messy, and to make it as performant as possible...?

Comment: Does vue-router not emit an event that you could listen on, and set your data variable to `false` in response to?

Comment: There are some, but which to use? And how? `router.beforeEach`, `router.beforeResolve`, `router.afterEach` etc...

Comment: Also there is the current active Route (`this.$route`) but this property is read-only and its properties are immutable, but the docs say it can be watched...? How?

Comment: And also potentially `$route.params`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Watched](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) property of Vue to watch for changes in your route like:

```
watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      console.log("route changed");
      this.someVariable = false;
    }
  }
```

More about the Route Object in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object).

Comment: Thanks Adres! Worked like a charm - was this in the documentation?

Comment: Not directly but you can see more about The Route Object in the documentation. https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object

Comment: Thanks Andres - that was really useful. I appreciate you sending that after the answer was accepted! Thank you :)